GCP NGFW with TLS inspection make it failed to browse HTTPs website
After enabling the TLS Inspection option under firewall policy, I cannot browse the HTTPS websites anymore. I used both enterprise CA and dev CA. [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/8pJrjdTK.png)
Without TLS inspection it worked. Configured the TRUST also.
